# R-Kernel keeps dying after install "easyGgplot2" package.

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed the eachGgplot2 package for my project which is causing my R-kernel to keep dying on Jupyter Notebook. I tried uninstalling and installing Anaconda (both the simple remove and clean remove methods) but did not solve the problem.  Below are the codes that I used before my R-kernel committed suicide:

`install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("easyGgplot2", "kassambara")`

The log shows the errors in a package called "digest"

`KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called 'digest'
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>`

I do not really need this easyGgplot2 library - what should I do to get my R-kernel back up running?

Any help and tip is most appreciated!

Comment: Did `install.packages("devtools")` really successfully run without installing the `digest` package? I would have expected that to be a dependency. Is there no error before that? What R version and OS are you using here?

Comment: @MrFlick I don't recall whether or not install.package ("devtools") ran successfully but I would presume it did because otherwise I would have stopped  before running the install_github("easyGgplot2", "kassambara"). I am using R x64 3.5.1 and Windows  10pro. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the R-Kernel on Jupyter Notebook.  I want to post the solution in case anyone else runs into similar problem in the future.   @MrFlick you were right that the problem is at the Devtool even thought in R console it says the packages "digest and "devtools" are installed successfully.  I remove the devtool package from the R-console using `remove.packages('Devtools')` and that revive my R-kernel on Jupyter Notebook.  Thanks.